# Host is not resolved but connecting via telnet, can somebody explain how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, telnet, nc

In aws ec2 instance, rds host name is not resolved by ping or nslookup but it is still able to reach via telnet or nc how ?

```
~# nslookup xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve
```

but in nc

```
~# nc -vv  xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com (xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3306) open
```

Can somebody explain me How this is possible ?

Comment: Your `nslookup` seems broken. What OS is this?

Comment: ec2 instance  : ubuntu 16.04

Comment: but other hosts are resolved by nslookup

Comment: A simple guess, does nc use alternative method than dns to resolve the hostname ? I ask, as on windows in exemple iexplore default to use netbios name resolution before using the dns's one.

Comment: Local `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: RDS doesn't respond to ping, but nslookup should work. I wonder if this is a typo? Cannot resolve (null) suggests a problem with your nslookup.